# Convert String of Strings to List<String> Java

Tags: java

How convert following `String` with string values to `List<String>`:

```
[null,294,160,199,105]
```

Comment: You can [edit] your post to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: What have you tried, and what if troubling you? I mean, it's a simple loop with format-to-string, so which part of that can;t you figure out?

Comment: Do you have an array (title of your question) or a String (your question)?

Comment: `null` isn't an `int` value.

Comment: this is a string with values

Comment: A string object with numbers separated by comma ',' right ?

Comment: trying to convert string with string values to List<String>

Comment: Rishabh Kumar - yes

Comment: Saying a String has values just means it's not empty.

Comment: So what should be output? A list having 5 values as null, 294, 160, 199, 105

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
List<String> result = Arrays.asList(
    input.substring(1, input.length() - 1).split(",")
);
```

Comment: It works with above string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can try this one...

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String field : inputStr.split(","))
    lst.add(field);
```

Comment: Arrays.asList(str.split(",")); remove first and last chars from the string (the [ and ]) before splitting

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at the following API:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) is about splitting a String by a delimiter
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html is about using regular expressions in Java

You should find there enough information to solve this on your own.